# How to call a method of C++ model in QML while using QQuickWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, openstreetmap

qqI'm trying to integrate a map window using OSM plugin which can also add multiple markers on picked points on the map. Trying to display the map using QQuickWidget by giving map.qml file as source using GUI Designer. The map display widget is part of mainwindow i.e another widget.

I tried implementing
https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/49344638 with few changes.
In this example QQuickWindow is created from main.cpp and used. I have done it using GUI Designer. I have set the ContextProperty of root context creating a object of model, but getting errors while trying to access the object from qml file. Also got
QML Map: Plugin is a write-once property, and cannot be set again  error once. I'm new to using qml and c++ not sure what the issue is..
Thanks in advance
locationMarker.h

```
#ifndef LOCATIONMARKER_H
#define LOCATIONMARKER_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>

class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;
  enum MarkerRoles { positionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1 };

  Q_INVOKABLE void addMarker(const QGeoCoordinate &coordinate) {
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_coordinates.append(coordinate);
    endInsertRows();
  }

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return m_coordinates.count();
  }

  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index,
                int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_coordinates.count())
      return QVariant();
    if (role == MarkerModel::positionRole)
      return QVariant::fromValue(m_coordinates[index.row()]);
    return QVariant();
  }

  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[positionRole] = "position";
    return roles;
  }

private:
  QList<QGeoCoordinate> m_coordinates;
};
#endif // LOCATIONMARKER_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
        #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
        #include "locationMarker.h"
    
        #include <QQmlContext>
        #include <QQuickWidget>
        #include <QQmlEngine>
    
        MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
            : QMainWindow(parent)
            , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
        {
            ui->setupUi(this);
            MarkerModel model;
            ui->quickWidget->engine()->rootContext()- 
     >setContextProperty("markerModel", &model);
            ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/map.qml"));
        }
    
        MainWindow::~MainWindow()
        {
            delete ui;
        }
```

map.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
Item {
    id: qmlMap

    Plugin {
    id: osmPlugin
    name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        id: mapview
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapItemView{
            model: markerModel
            delegate: mapcomponent
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressAndHold:  {
                var coordinate = mapview.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
                markerModel.addMarker(coordinate)
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: mapcomponent
        MapQuickItem {
            id: marker
            anchorPoint.x: image.width/4
            anchorPoint.y: image.height
            coordinate: position

            sourceItem: Image {
                id: image
                source: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error from qml

TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMarker' of null

Comment: provide [mcve] instead of explaining your code

Comment: You create `MarkerModel` instance on the stack, it will be deleted after you exit the `MainWindow` constructor. You probably have to use that as a class member instead.

Comment: Thank youuu, solved the issue.